# MySql unistall and reinstall, but doesn't work

Tags: mysql

on my Windows 10, I had a old mySql installation. I uninstalled it by following [this](https://old.windowsvalley.com/uninstall-mysql-from-windows/) tutorial and, from control panel -> software install, I uninstalled all items starting by name mysql (only, I have seen in this phase that My Sql Connector 8.0.16, after "uninstall" button pressing, confirm and waiting message, is again present in the list).

Then, I restarted the computer and I downloaded mysql-installer-community-8.0.18.0 and executed. First, I have seen a "welcome back" message (but I have all uninstalled). And, in the list of the available items, I see the windows "select product to upgrade" and then only a connector/NET and nothing else. But I don't want it, I want the entire mysql reinstall.

Sure, mySql has not completely uninstalled. How can I solve the problem? Have you a more powerful procedure to the entire mysql really uninstall, or can you suggest me other steps not present in the previous tutorial which I have already followed?

Edit: after 2 times reg key deleting, restart computer and reinstall, finally works! Only, I see the following error by "Connector/.NET" component. I can't uninstall or upgrade it.

```
    1: Action 13:20:32: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.18 2: {6A8D895A-E2D0-4701-BE5D-478BEAC048D3} 
1: Action 13:20:32: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 13:20:32: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 13:20:32: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 13:20:32: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 13:20:32: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 13:20:32: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 13:20:32: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 13:20:32: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 13:20:32: Setv45InstallUtil. 
1: Action 13:20:32: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 13:20:32: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Application: {0160C4A1-392C-4AFA-B8DB-2471FDA71425}, Command line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={6A8D895A-E2D0-4701-BE5D-478BEAC048D3} CLIENTPROCESSID=7112 CLIENTUILEVEL=3 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 REMOVE=ALL
1: Action 13:20:32: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.16 2: {0160C4A1-392C-4AFA-B8DB-2471FDA71425} 
1: Action 13:20:32: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 13:20:32: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver5081
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver507
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver506
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver505
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver504
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver503
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver502
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver501
1: Property: OLDVERSION, Signature: Ver500
1: Property: PREUPGRADEVERSION, Signature: Pre638
1: Property: PERUSERINSTALL, Signature: Reg638
1: Property: PERUSERINSTALL, Signature: Reg644
1: Property: HLM_LOCATION, Signature: HLMRegSearch
1: Property: NETFRAMEWORK45, Signature: NetFramework45
1: Action 13:20:32: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 13:20:32: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 13:20:32: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 13:20:32: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 13:20:32: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 13:20:32: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 13:20:32: Setv45InstallUtil. 
1: Action 13:20:32: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 13:20:32: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
1: InstallInitialize
1: Action 13:20:32: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Action 13:20:32: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: 
1: Action 13:20:32: MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Unpublishing assembly information
1: Application Context:Unpublishing assembly information, Assembly Name:
1: Action 13:20:32: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
1: Feature: Unpublishing Product Features
1: Action 13:20:32: UninstallPerfCounterData. 
1: Action 13:20:32: RollbackUnregisterPerfCounterData. 
1: 
1: Action 13:20:32: UnregisterPerfCounterData. 
1: 
1: Action 13:20:32: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
1: Key: Removing system registry values, Name: 
1: Action 13:20:33: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
1: Shortcut: Removing shortcuts
1: Action 13:20:33: ManagedDataUnInstallSetup. 
1: Action 13:20:33: ManagedDataUnInstall. Unregistering data provider from machine.config
1: Action 13:20:33: ManagedWebUnInstallSetup. 
1: 
1: Action 13:20:33: RemoveFiles. Removing files
1: File: Removing files, Directory: 
1: Action 13:20:33: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
1: Folder: Removing folders
1: Action 13:20:33: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Action 13:20:33: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: Action 13:20:33: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Action 13:20:33: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Action 13:20:33: InstallPerfCounterData. 
1: Action 13:20:33: RegisterUser. Registering user
1: Action 13:20:33: RegisterProduct. Registering product
1: Action 13:20:33: MsiPublishAssemblies. Publishing assembly information
1: Action 13:20:33: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
1: Action 13:20:33: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: 
1: Action 13:20:33: InstallFinalize. 
1: Action 13:20:33: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 13:20:33: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 13:20:33: MsiUnpublishAssemblies. Unpublishing assembly information
1: Application Context:Global, Assembly Name:MySql.Data,version="8.0.16.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D",processorArchitecture="MSIL"
1: Application Context:Global, Assembly Name:Google.Protobuf,version="3.6.1.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="A7D26565BAC4D604",processorArchitecture="MSIL"
1: Application Context:Global, Assembly Name:BouncyCastle.Crypto,version="1.8.3.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="0E99375E54769942"
1: Application Context:Global, Assembly Name:MySql.Web,version="8.0.16.0",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D",processorArchitecture="MSIL"
1: Action 13:20:33: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
1: Feature: EntityFramework
1: Feature: Core.Feature
1: Feature: WebProviders
1: Feature: Plugins
1: Action 13:20:33: RollbackUnregisterPerfCounterData. 
1: Action 13:20:33: UnregisterPerfCounterData. 
1: Action 13:20:33: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB, Name: Default
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Connector/Net, Name: Version
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Connector/Net, Name: Location
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Connector/Net, Name: 
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.5.50709\AssemblyFoldersEx\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.16 v4.5.1, Name: 
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.5.50709\AssemblyFoldersEx\MySQL Connector Net 8.0.16 v4.5.1, Name: 
1: Action 13:20:33: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
1: Shortcut: upfn1-0t|Documentation
1: Shortcut: vaitcdd6|ChangeLog
1: Shortcut: _rq6aex9|Release Notes
1: Action 13:20:38: ManagedDataUnInstall. Unregistering data provider from machine.config
1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.16 2: {0160C4A1-392C-4AFA-B8DB-2471FDA71425} 3: 3 
1: Action 13:20:38: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: Unregistering data provider from machine.config
1: Removing shortcuts
1: Removing system registry values
1: UnregisterPerfCounterData
1: RollbackUnregisterPerfCounterData
1: Unpublishing Product Features
1: Unpublishing assembly information
1: Updating component registration
1: InstallInitialize
1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.18 2: {6A8D895A-E2D0-4701-BE5D-478BEAC048D3} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Upgrade' for product 'Connector/NET 8.0.18' failed.
```

EDIT: I also asked in the official mysql forum, but after days my question is not yet approved from the forum staff. I don't know the reason.

Comment: According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-installer-uninstalling.html) and [this](https://old.windowsvalley.com/uninstall-mysql-from-windows/) you may need to remove MySQL directories in your program and AppData directories too.

Comment: As already written, is exactly what I have done. Ah, no, I have done much more than this link! And it doesn't work. Can you please suggest me step that I didn't mentioned above? Thank your for your time ad for your help.

Comment: Maybe it left a registry entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MySQL AB` or
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB`. See https://coderanch.com/t/490277/databases/Clean-full-registry-MySQL-uninstall

Comment: No, doesn't work. I see the same situation. I also copy the entire output message from the installer in my original post, I see that after installing procedure. I am desperate.

Comment: Yes, it's works! Thank you very much for your help, after reg key deleting, restart, reinstall, and one other time the same operation mysql works fine. Only, last problem: the Connector / Net component. In the list of components, it appears with an error icon. I can't do nothing with this connector: I can't uninistall from applications installer manager, I can't remove or upgrade from mySql installer. I copied the complete log in main topic. How can I delete and reinstall? Thank you very much!

Comment: Where does it occur? Just delete the link?

Comment: Thank for your reply and sorry for the delay. It occour in mySql Installer -> 2nd step (select product to upgrade, and now I see only connector / NET item) -> Execute -> it stops at 52% and I see exactly the log in main question (right now updated). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) find executed service or exe from task manager. NOTE : (if you not found any thing so are successfully done uninstall Mysql)

2) open file location and make remember.

3) then stop mysql services or exe from task manager
 and  also  delete files from folder exist in folder location (which i previous told for do remember ).

Comment: Thank you very much, right now I almost solved the problem. And I already done the operations you write. I only should resolve a Connector / NET problem, I update the orignal question with the complete log. Can you see it? Thank

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql Installer Community, it shows "welcome back" message and in the list of the available items, "select product to upgrade" and then only a connector/NET.

Click Cancel button and it would proceed to next step. There, select the add button and add the required installation to be done.

Then install the required software.